# Sorting users based on scores

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Within my rails app, for each user, this is how I am calculating their score:

```
<% comment_vote_count = @user.comments.map{|c| c.votes.count}.sum

   comment_vote_count ||=0 

   comment_vote_count *= 2

   final_score = comment_vote_count + @user.base_score %>
```

This is just rendered in some of the views and is not saved in the database anywhere.

I'm trying to populate a list of all users in the order of highest score to least highest score as well as paginate the results.

This is what I have in my controller:

```
  def user_list
    @users = User.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

In my user_list view

```
<ol>
<%= render (@users) %>
</ol>

<%= will_paginate @users, :next_label => “next” , :previous_label => '', :class => "next_pagination" %>
```

How do I render an ordered list of users based on their scores? Should I be storing the scores in the database?

Comment: It's just a base score assigned to each user. This is stored in the database

Comment: @Katie H first thing you should not write business logic in view. Now to your question, you have business logic to get vote count for a single user, use same logic in user model with all users. Iterate all users, use same logic to get vote count, push them into an array and sort in order of your choice.

Comment: How would I do this? What if I have thousands of users? Should I iterate through all of them??

Comment: @KatieH approach presented by magnum2002 will return users collection much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PostGreSQL as your database backend and not afraid to get your hands dirty, then you can replace

```
@users = User.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

with

```
@users = User.select('u.*, 2 * case when count(v.id) is null then 0 else count(v.id) end + u.score as cnt')
             .from('users u').joins('left join comments c on c.user_id = u.id')
             .joins('left join votes v on v.comment_id = c.id')
             .group('u.id').order('cnt desc').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

I tested this on a local database both in the Rails console and psql and they gave the same result -- the users ordered in descending order by total score. The generated query is

```
SELECT u.id, 2 * case when count(v.id) is null then 0 else count(c.votes) end + u.score as cnt
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN comments c on c.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN votes v on v.comment_id = c.id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY cnt desc
```

which performs the calculation you are looking for. The `case` statement is necessary because PG returns `NULL` instead of `0` when summing all `NULL`s.

Comment: this really a very good approach, but you are mistaken with votes being attribute of comments, votes is another table, see her code se is using associative call user.comments[index].votes.

Answer (score 2):

`Comment` belongs to `User`, so each time someone vote this comment you can add to this comment owner points. I'd add a column to user called for ex: `score` of type `:integer` and then when some one votes you'll update this user `score` field:

```
user = @comment.user
score = @comment.votes.count
user.score = score
user.save
```

then order users directly by `score` column:

```
User.order("score DESC")
```

in case with act_as_voteable gem

**Vote.rb**

```
after_create :add_score_to_user

def add_score_to_user
  user = self.voteable.user # gets comment user as voteable is a comment
  score = self.voteable.votes.count # votes count of a comment
  user.score = score
  user.save
  # or user.update_attributes(score: score) instead of last 2 lines
end
```

if you want to add only one point to user score after each vote you could use `increment`:

```
def add_score_to_user
  user = self.voteable.user # gets comment user as voteable is a comment
  user.increment!(:score) # this will add +1 to user score for each vote
end
```

p.s.

```
rails g migration add_score_to_users score:integer
```

edit the migration to set the score default to `0` then:

```
User.order("score DESC").order('id DESC')
```

Comment: This will be faster, and easy to maintain, as each time while voting OP surely would be having a ajax call.

Comment: True, thank God ajax call is not that hard to build ;)

Comment: How do I run this? With a after_save call? Where do I put this?

Comment: @KatieH, you need to run this in action where a vote is submitted, or if or in after_create/before_save callback, after vote is saved.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that user.rb contains:

```
has_many :votes, through: :comments
```

You will need an initializer for this

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

But then controller is as simple as:

```
@users=User.all.map {|i| [i.votes.count,i]}.sort.reverse.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

And in your view:

```
@users.each do |user|...
```

user[0] is vote count
user[1] contains your fields (example: user[1].id, etc)

Comment: The user.rb does not have that. I am using the acts_as_votable gem, the user acts as the voter and the comments act as votable

Comment: That's great. Lol, it's still a good solution, but not for you :) Sorry